# Constantly getting git error "port 22: Network is unreachable" with no clear cause

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-push, git-pull

I'm using Fork as a git client. Recently, whenever I try to push/pull/fetch from a remote repository I get this error:

> Pushing to bitbucket.org:(repository)
> ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I first tried making a new ssh key and that seemed to fix the problem, but then it started up again. I then tried turning off my firewall/antivirus which also only worked for a day or two before I got the error once more. My internet connection is stable and I definitely have access to the remote repository I'm trying to connect to. I haven't tested it with any other repositories because this is the only one I actively need to use.

At this point, I have no idea what the problem could possibly be because it seems almost random when it does or doesn't work. Just now I attempted to push 3 times and I kept getting the error, and then suddenly it worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is really starting to interfere with my team's workflow.

Comment: "Network is unreachable" is an error that comes from your networking stack. It has nothing to do with ssh itself (or Git), it's just that either your network itself is flaky (goes down a lot) or your IP stack in your OS is terrible (thinks the network is dead when it's actually fine), or both.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that issues like [`fork-dev/TrackerWin` issue 923](https://github.com/fork-dev/TrackerWin/issues/923) have been fixed since 2020, I would switch, for testing, to an HTTPS URL in order to see if the issue persists

Using a git credential helper like "`manager`" (the [GCM Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) bundled with Git), you can cache your BitBucket credentials, and still pull/push like you were doing before with SSH.